# eclipse bundle and lib-folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, bundle

I have created an eclipse plugin/bundle which needs some additional jar-files. these jar-files are located in the 'lib'-folder and added to the build-path. so far, so good.
If I launch the application which uses the bundle, I get exceptions. It looks like the required jar-files are not known anymore. I'm confused.
all of our bundles (the others work fine) appear in the bundle cache (../configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/) and they contain their.jar + the lib-folder with all jars this bundle needs.
in the problematic bundle the lib-folder is missing.
other bundles from other people do not appear at all in this cache. why? should they appear there? if not, what am I doing wrong? if yes, how do I have to configure my bundle that it doe not miss the required jars?
can anybody help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which build path did you add them to? The project one, or the MANIFEST.MF->runtime->Classpath one? They need to be in the MANIFEST.MF file for them to be on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: I was wondering if it's correct to put them into the manifest classpath entry (Eclipse help does not recommend to put anything there) but obviously it's the way it whould be... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Even though the lib is on the build path, it may not be included in the build output. Open the `plugin.xml` or plugin manifest file, select the **Build** tab. Examine the **Binary Buil**d section to see if the JAR(s) from `/lib` are being included.

Comment: the /lib folder is inlcuded: bin.includes = lib/